# dojo grid: naviagion

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid

I am exploring dojo grid, and could not find a good example of how to handle navigation by clicking on the row.

There is a simple grid example [here](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2011/01/31/a-simple-dojo-datagrid-example-or-so-close-yet-wide-right/)

How to extend the code with the following requirement

1. handle doubleclick event on row items
2. read the identifier and extract the value corresponding to the selected row ( 12 for first row)
3. redirect to {current domain}/view/{identifier}  (like www.example.com/view/12)

any help would be a great time saver...

thanks.

EDIT: added javascript tag so that more user may see this post (only 9 so far with dojo alone)

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve problems 1 and 2 above.
You can use dojo.connect to connect the grid to the onRowClick event.  For example, if you have a grid of the form:

```
        <div dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="grid" id="myGrid" structure="layout" selectionMode="single"></div>
```

You can then call in JavaScript:

```
dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", clickMethod);
```

clickMethod can then access the data from the row as follows:

```
function clickMethod(event) {
...
selected_index = grid.focus.rowIndex;
selected_item = grid.getItem(selectedIndex);
//Not sure if this is the most efficient way but it worked for me
selected_id = grid.store.getValue(selectedItem, "field_name_from_store");
...
}
```

I imagine you can do a location.href or similar after that.